# How can I connect to PostgreSQL using PowerBI via HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: postgresql, http, powerbi

I have a PostgreSQL database hosted by a platform that only authorizes HTTP/HTTPS for in and out traffic. I want to access to this database from PowerBI. I can't deploy a PowerBI Gateway as I can't deploy Windows machine on this platform.

**How can I connect to this postgreSQL database from PowerBI though HTTP/HTTPS ?**

I thought about using [Postgrest](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/) to generate a Rest API over my database and then connect PowerBI to this API but I can't find any resources to do that.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?